# Conceptual doubt with an orthogonal complement problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I'm asked to find the orthogonal complement of $H\subset\mathbb R^4, H=\text{span\{(2,-1,0,0},(0,1,0,-2),(-8,0,0,8)\}$. But after doing the math, I got that the solution is a vector of the form $(a,2a,c,a)$. However, the complement I found has dimension 2, but shouldn't it actually have dimension one?

Thanks for attention

Comment: No. $H$ has dimension $2$ and not $3$ as the vectors are linearly dependent.